# Git hub repository issue with vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, repository

I have just started GitHub, when I try to add a file I get the error "The git repository at 'c\Users\TonyD' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled. I have not added any files but it has 10,000. How do I delete them?

I expected to load my first "Hello world" code under test.py

Comment: how many other questions are there on SO about VSC and 10K git files? A lot.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you created a repository in your user folder, which means that you're uploading every single one of your files to GitHub.

If you're using Git Bash, you can run the following commands, using whatever folder name you'd like:

```bash
mkdir folder_name
cd folder_name
git init
```

Or you can create a repository on GitHub and then clone it to your computer, and then add whatever files you want to the folder you cloned.